# Cakephp 3.x redirect not working in the same controller using another method in same function

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I am using **cakephp 3.x** and i have an **edit** function in my controller in which i am checking whether id is in the query string or not as well as whether is it exists in the database record or not. Here below is my code which is working perfectly fine.

**UsersController.php**

```
public function edit($id = null)    
{

    // first checking whether id sent or not .. 
    if(empty($this->request->params['pass']))
    {
        $this->Flash->error('Invalid Action');
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }        


    // Now checking whether this user id exists or 

    $check_user = $this->Users
                    ->find()
                    ->where(['user_id' => $id])
                    ->toArray();
    if(!$check_user)
    {
         $this->Flash->error('Invalid Id, User not found');
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }

    $user = $this->Users->get($id); 

    // And so on 
 }
```

The thing is, i am using this same code in many other functions to check the same thing so i had comeup creating a common function in the same controller and use it in multiple functions like below.

**UsersController.php** *(Updated)*

```
public function checkId($id)
{
    // first checking whether id sent or not .. 
    if(empty($this->request->params['pass']))
    {
        $this->Flash->error('Invalid Action');
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }        


    // Now checking whether this user id exists or 

    $check_user = $this->Users
                    ->find()
                    ->where(['user_id' => $id])
                    ->toArray();
    if(!$check_user)
    {
         $this->Flash->error('Invalid Id, User not found');
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
}

public function edit($id = null)    
{
    $this->checkId($id);
}
```

Now if i execute the url in my browser **http://localhost/5p_group/users/edit/** , i get this error saying **Record not found in table "users" with primary key [NULL]**

Can someone guide me how to fullfil both these 2 conditions (check id in the url or not as well as is it valid id or not) using common function which i have created above .. it is working absolutely fine if i put that code inside my same **edit()** function.

Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The problem is, its not redirecting at all .. if i put **die('test');** in my **edit()** function just after my this code **$this->checkId($id);** its showing this message but it should not be .. it should redirect as i have not typed **id** in the url itself which works fine if i put the same code in my **edit** function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you forgot to add function parameter $id, you already use it in the query

```
public function checkId()
```

change to

```
public function checkId($id)
```

[Update]

Here is also a function return issue

```
if(empty($id))
{
    $this->Flash->error('Invalid Action');
    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
}
```

change to >>

```
if(empty($id))
{
    $this->Flash->error('Invalid Action');
    $this->response = $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']) ;
    $this->response->send () ;
    die () ;
}
```

Comment: i have updated my code in my question above .. but it still does not work for me. Having same error.

Comment: may be you did not understand my requirement properly i am afraid.

Comment: if you didn't pass the user id in url then $this->checkId($id); here id will be null and you will get the error  "users" with primary key [NULL]

Comment: but that is what i am checking using **if(empty($this->request->params['pass']))** in my code.

Comment: you have another mismatch in  if(empty($this->request->params['pass'])) not working, just use if(empty($id))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125089/discussion-between-mittul-at-technobrave-and-tarikul05).